# Why are header files bad design?

Tags: design, headers

[this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180904/are-header-files-actually-good) says header files are bad design, but I don't know why.  The answers specified there are about the inefficiency of header file when building.  Why it is *bad design* is not really touched upon.

As far as I know:
- headers lets you break the source file up so you can compile smaller things faster
- headers lets you separate the interface from the implementation
- headers lets you specify functionality in only one place. ie. no repeating

Yet using includes, include guards, headers, etc. are considered bad design.  How so?  What are the alternatives?

-- EDIT: re. DRY issues

A common argument is that it violates DRY in that you repeat changes in signatures in both the .cpp and .h files.  However, if the code is designed to reuse functionality specified in outside files, is it not unavoidable that header files must be used?

The question asks why header files are bad design, yet without the headers, is modularity not lost?  If modularity is lost, is that not itself a design issue?  Thus using header files averts a separate design issue.

Repeating in general is a bad idea, I get that, but it seems unavoidable if you require common functionality. In which case headers are bad, in terms of signature repetition. In terms of how you design your software, I'm inclined to say that splitting code up/modularizing, and reusing code means your code is designed well.

Comment: it violates DRY in the worst way

Comment: @ratchet: then how are you supposed to get the outside code functionality in?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the question you have linked to.  Answers there provide ample explanation of why this is bad design.

Comment: in terms of inneficiency, the reasons are listed in the link; *design-wise*, not seeing the answer

Comment: I think the inefficiencies are the design problem. The existence of header files doesn't really impact the design of your software - when I'm decomposing requirements to components and then designing those components, the fact that C and C++ use header files and Java and other languages don't doesn't really concern me. The design issue is in the design of the language and its supporting tools (compilers, parsers, IDEs, etc), which is addressed by some answers in that question.

Comment: If the existence of header files does not really impact the design of the software, then the *only* problem with header files *is* the inefficient building.  But then that means the language is the one that has the design problem.  Designing the software to use headers, while inefficient to build, stops you from cutting/pasting functions into multiple files. ie. cluttering files with extra logic that should exist elsewhere.

Comment: @user2738698 Using header files is *efficient* building.  That is why it is done, not for providing some program design edge.  It derives from an older age of compilers when that was the only way it could be done in reasonable time.

Comment: @user2738698 Do you understand what computational power was available when C was developed? Do you understand the underlying hardware? It doesn't sound like you do, and those things are important to know to understand why header files exist.

Comment: Yes, I understand the computational power back then and the reason for using headers; at the very least, I read through the link I provided.  I'm wondering about why *other people* say it is bad design to use header files.  I use them all of the time, since I program in c++ mostly.

Comment: Okay so I write a class. I write a couple of methods, like say `Startup(int iCount)`. And then I discover my class needs something else for this method, say a data structure, like so: `Startup(int iCount, void *pS)`. So I not only need to change the signature of the method in the .c/.cpp file but also in the .h file. I am doing the same work in two different files.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because people don't understand the real question.  He's asking **when he is using C++** if there's a good alternative to using header files.  Not if there's a good alternative in another language.

Comment: Yes, that is repeating yourself twice.  Then consider the alternative: when you *don't* use the header.  Instead you physically write Startup(int iCount, void \*pS) in *each* file that needs it.  The only alternative then is to include the .cpp file instead.

Comment: Also, everyone who thinks it's a DRY issue should think about how many `interface`s they are using in their code.

Comment: Then they need to say that Karl. Its not incumbent on us to read their mind. Look at this thread and others where people attempted to figure what they wanted or were trying to ask.

Comment: If I didn't know better, it would seem as though you were trying to prove why repeating method signatures (header or otherwise) is a good idea.  I hope I'm not mistaken in thinking this isn't the case?

Comment: Repeating in general is a bad idea, I get that, but it seems unavoidable if you require common functionality.  In which case headers are bad, in terms of signature repetition.  In terms of how you design your software, I'm inclined to say that splitting code up/modularizing, and reusing code means your code is designed well.

Comment: @user2738698 but header files are in no way required to write modular, reuseable code! As I explained in my answer, there are other options for linking than baking in external definitions via header files.

Comment: @amon that's why I voted yours up, because it answered one of the questions above. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer looks at header files from a language design perspective. My point is not that you shouldn't *use* headers in your C or C++ programs – headers are required by these languages. Instead, this answer is an argument that you shouldn't design *new* languages that use header files.

---

Header files are bad language design, at least from a modern perspective:

- Header files in C are a bad design not least because C's macro system is bad: it works via token substitution, not on an AST level. This means:

  - It barfs on circular includes
  - It means that the same stuff is compiled multiple times
  - A seemingly short and simple program might grow to a gigantic behemoth due to a few includes.
  - It is incredibly limited (compared to what the gold standard of macros – Lisp – can do).
- Header files are bad because they are files. And these files are separate from the actual code. Or not: nobody is preventing you from putting code in the header as well. Why shouldn't the header be in the same file as the source code? There is no solid technical reason for not doing this unless single-pass compilation of each compilation unit is required.
- Headers are bad because a non-naive compiler can jolly well figure out forward references of symbols without having these be pre-declared. Predeclarations are only useful if a multi-pass compiler is not an option for some reason. Pre-declarations have no value for a human reader (it's a massive DRY violation), and add too little value for a compiler.

And now to refute some possible rebuttals of the “headers are bad” idea:

- “*Without headers we can't link against libraries*” – I'm sure that's true for C and descendants (which unfortunately are ubiquitous), but this doesn't hold for other languages.

  - A simple alternative is to directly use the source code of a library to extract the interface (this is how many scripting languages like Perl or Python kind of work).
  - This may not be desirable in closed-source environments, where the compiler output could be used to link against (which is roughly how Java works, where `.class` files contain the interface alongside the executable bytecode).

  The key point is not that no link specification exists, the key is that this specification isn't written by humans.
- “*Without headers we can't share things (functions, macros, classes) between files*” – yes we can, with things like namespaces and modules containing these things. Let's say I have a `#define PI 3.1415` in some C code. To share that definition between my source files, I'd have to `#include "my_math_constans.h"` or something. Python's solution `from math import pi` which loads the `math` module and imports the `pi` symbol from that module into the current scope works at least just as well.

Comment: basically your post is "headers are bad because someone types them out, and they're good if generated automatically by the compiler". In no place do you make the case for or against header files themselves :)

Comment: @gbjbaanb I do argue against header **files**: “*Header files are bad because they are files. And these files are separate from the actual code. […] Why shouldn't the header be in the same file as the source code? There is no solid technical reason for not doing this*”. But you are correct that the main thrust of my argument is against human-generated headers per se.

Comment: fair enough, though at times I wish for a header file - when I see a C# partial class spread over many files with some extension methods added in for good measure. IIRC the C++ committee want to get rid of headers, but I guess they'll have to mandate changes to compilers to emit a binary standard.. which would be a good thing in itself, especially as it means you wouldn't be locked into a proprietary editor and/or compiler.

Comment: Oh god, partial classes... they make me want to smack some coders somewhere, usually. All I will say on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Header files are a legacy of C's heritage - it was written to be close to the hardware, but abstracted enough to run on similar platforms, if a compiler is made for the platform.

What header files do is they define symbols other files can use without the compiler having an issue. The compiler then replaces the symbolic reference with a link or copy of the actual code.

The design issue with this is that you have to repeat yourself. You define the same symbols in two separate files, and when one changes(say a method signature or a class name), the other must be changed as well.

This violates DRY - "Don't Repeat Yourself". This creates an automatic dependency on another file due to the header files. So then when trying to figure out what the objects and classes are doing, you need both, as there's a tonne of syntactical knobs that can turned in either file.

Comment: If you need functionality twice in two different files then, how do you give both the files the same functionality without repeating yourself?

Comment: @user2738698 You're talking about something entirely different.  The header and source files are not repetitions of code.  They are repetitions of method signatures.

Comment: Ok, they are repetitions of method signatures; even then, the question still stands, if you try to maintain DRY, how can you give both files the same functionality without repeating method signatures?

Comment: How is this related to your question? You don't give them the same functionality. You asked why header files are bad design, and you've been answered. It sounds like you're actually after something else.

Comment: If they're needed to include functionality inside other files, you can't help but repeat your inclusions.  If three different pieces of code perform separate tasks but all require using a common calculation at one point, designing your software to not repeat that calculation's logic in each function seems a better design than otherwise.

Comment: @user2738698 It's true that you would have to repeat the method's *signature* in the header, but the logic is in the source file exactly once if you do it right.  I don't think that technically qualifies as "repeating yourself".  It isn't following DRY in that it is a hassle to have to make corrections in both the source and the header files.

Comment: @Zeroth oh well, you just made the case against Interfaces, and WSDLs, and IDLs :( I think you might be taking the DRY principle a little too far.

Comment: Well, that's what the Common Sense Principle is for gbjbaanb: if following one principle will cause issues, its better not to do it.  Interfaces, WSDLs, IDLs offer power and capability and solve problems that are not solely solved by DRY. So its a trade off that should be kept in mind - using interfaces can contribute to Inheritance Fragility, which is itself a sign of a not very good design.

Comment: Meanwhile, the duplication of effort in source files/header files *doesn't* offer any significant power or solve problems.